# How do I combine multiple meshes during runtime on a single skeleton?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

My intention is to make a game with mechs you can customize. Much in the way you can do this in front mission games. Unique models for arms / legs / etc, and at runtime they can be combined on a single rig. Doing this in XNA by the way.

I've been struggling however, with the work flow, as well as the implementation (so everything).

The idea that i'm going with is having a template model with the full skeleton in place, then make components with bones named the same bone names (example: shoulder -> forearm bone for an arm model) then at runtime, when you're doing the customization bit, stitch the parts together using the reference skeleton + all the parts mesh data.

This idea requires that the names of bones persist when I export to .fbx, which I don't think they do (?)

Is there any named entity that I can export out with a FBX model? If there is, and it's not a bone, then that solves the problem! (I think!).

Dump some knowledge on me, please.

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with any implementation yet?

Comment: Bone names are preserved, you can get a bone by name like this: `Model.Bones["boneName"];`

Comment: Meshes also act the same way as above

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, then I think the tutorial [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/skinned_model_extensions) could be what you are looking for.  It is an extension of the Skinned Model tutorial, but shows you how to add additional models to the bones within your Skinned Model.  In their example, it adds a bat to one of the hands of the Dude model.